# Localization in DDD

Tags: localization, domain-driven-design

I have a list of physics parameters (like Pressure, Voltage and etc.) accessible to all users from all tenants (multi-tenant application). Now, I need a way to display appropriate language to different users.

Parameter is an aggregate root:

```
class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
}
```

I need a way to localize both name and description. My first approach was this:

```
class Parameter
{
    public IDictionary<Locale, NameAndDescription> Info { get; }
}
```

but I feel somehow that this is not correct.

Also, administrators will want to write different translations in the UI. But users will want to see only selected translation (switchable if needed).

How should I solve this problem? Should I remove it completely from domain? Can my application layer have methods to write appropriate translations (facilitating administrators)? Should I resolve current locale from context or should I expect it to be passed to URI/DTO when hitting endpoints? Any other information on localization in DDD would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localization should be in another `bounded context`, probably implemented using a CRUD architecture as there are no business rules/invariants that need to be protected. Then, in the `UI`, using translation methods that access that `bounded context`, names of the `parameters` are displayed to the user according to their locale and/or administration settings.

Put it other way, localization does not seem to play any role inside your core domain, they do not participate in protecting the domain invariants.